# Migrating from SVN, can Azure DevOps be leveraged for exchanging files/folders between teams?

Tags: azure-devops

At my company, we use SVN for a dual purpose:

1. It's our code repository
2. It's where we upload and handoff folders to our production team.

Our production team has visibility into certain folders in the SVN repo, with read-only access.  We build "packages" for remote software distribution, which are a combination of our internal developed tools and vendor patches or security patches or whatever.

The reason we store these packages in SVN, is for the change tracking. We can tell if any developer makes a change, or at least have an audit trail when/if something goes wrong.

Our company-wide strategy is changing to move to Azure DevOps and we've easily shifted our code repositories there.

For SVN we use TortoiseSVN, where there's a repository browser and Developers can easily upload folders and Operations team can download them.

Can git/Azure DevOps be used for this use-case?
Or should we be eyeballing Azure Storage or some other Azure service for this scenario?

The key is that we require the audit trail and change tracking, not just a place to dump files/folders.

Also, some of these "packages" are gigabytes in size, which means it's not feasible to have the entire git repo downloaded all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did land on using git with Azure DevOps. The key for us was not to lump everything into one giant repo. Instead, we have one project with multiple repos.

Each repo represents a "package" as described in the question. In this approach, cloning a repo is no big deal. Our largest packages are <2GB. Most are <200MB.

A developer could have multiple repos cloned, but doesn't need to have every repo cloned, making the overall size/space requirements feasible.

When a developer has a new package or new revision, they create or clone the appropriate repo, make their changes/additions, and commit/push that to Azure DevOps.

Our Operations folks have read-only access to the repo, where they can download a ZIP of the package and import on their end, via the DevOps site. Thus the Ops folks don't need to be familiar with git command lines.

Using git, all the commits are tracked (and branched if necessary) so we have our audit trail of our developers activities, nicely visualized in Azure DevOps.

The mistake was looking at what we were doing in SVN and trying to fit that into git and Azure DevOps, without adjusting our approach.